# SwipeJS not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, swiper.js

```
My Swipe.Js version : "^7.0.2"
```

So I tried to use Swipe.Js today. When I'm importing I used this code line.

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'; 
as in https://swiperjs.com/react#installation.  But when I implement this I get error like this.
./src/App.jsx
Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper/react' in 'C:\Users\User.LAPTOP-3EBUUP6S\Desktop\My future projects\new\smart-parking-system\src'
```

So I looked at the node_modules folder and then I found where is the `Swiper` and `SwiperSlide` functions are. So I imported that file by using this line.
`import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react/swiper-react.js';`

But it also giving a error like this.

```
./node_modules/swiper/react/get-params.js
Module not found: Can't resolve 'swiper' in 'C:\Users\User.LAPTOP-3EBUUP6S\Desktop\My future projects\new\smart-parking-system\node_modules\swiper\react'
```

So how to import this in a correct way? I saw that there is file changings from Swiper 6 to 7 in the documentation.(https://swiperjs.com/react#installation) But showings(like
Styles Imports) of that link are not working. So I had to look at the node_modules and then had to do importing. But this importing Swiper and SwiperSlide is not working by the way. Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Downgrade your version to 6.8.4! It works like magic!